# Given an arbitrary series of positive real numbers that converges, can you construct a subseries that converges to an irrational?

Tags: sequences-and-series, constructive-mathematics

To start out, I can demonstrate that any series of real numbers has a subseries that converges to an irrational.

Proof: Consider a sequence of positive real numbers, $a_n$, for whom $\sum a_n \in \mathbb R$. Because the sum of $a_n$ converges to a real then $a_n\to0$. Now we can take a subsequence of $a_n$ that converges as quickly as we like, so I'm going to find some subsequence of $a_n$, $b_n$, that has the property that $3b_{n+1} \le b_n$. Now every subsequence of $b_n$ has a 'unique' sum, in that no other subsequence of $b_n$ has the same sum as it. There are an uncountable number of subsequnces of $b_n$ and a countable number of rationals, thus some subsequence $b_n$, which in turn is a subsequence of $a_n$, must have a sum that converges to an irrational.

Now I've shown that every series of positive real numbers has a subseries that converges to an irrational number. My question is: "*Is there an algorithm that would take in any series of real positive numbers that converges and would find a subseries that converges to an irrational number, and if  there is such an algorithm what is it?*"

Comment: I'd take a look at [Liouville's Approximation Theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LiouvillesApproximationTheorem.html).  If your chosen numbers decay rapidly enough then their sum converges to a transcendental number.

Comment: I think you can modify your method  to extract a subseries that converges to any number (rational or not) that's less than the sum of the series. Not sure whether this would count as an algorithm.

Comment: Say it converges to $a>0$ and pick $b>0,b<a.$ Your idea should make a subsequence converging (sum) to $b.$

Comment: @EthanBolker I can give you the sequence $a_n = (10, .5, .25, .125, \ldots)$. It's not hard to show that $\sum a_n = 11$ however there are no subsequences converging to $8$.

Comment: @EthanBolker  this seems too strong.  Take a decreasing sequence of positive numbers the sum of which converges to $.1$ and prepend $1$ in front.  The new series converges, to $1.1$, but no subsequence converges to $.75$.

Comment: @lulu I think the Liouville's Approximation Theorem is a good way to go, thanks for that idea.

Comment: @Ethan there is a general result that characterizes the possible sets of values you can get. For some series you indeed get an interval. For others you get a set homeomorphic to the Cantor set. The other possibility is a mixture of the two, a "cantorval". Z. Nitecki has a paper with details in the Monthly:

Comment: @Ethan [MR3418208](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=3418208). Nitecki, Zbigniew. *[Cantorvals and subsum sets of null sequences](http://www.jstor.org/stable/10.4169/amer.math.monthly.122.9.862)*. Amer. Math. Monthly **122** (2015), no. 9, 862–870. (Also available at the author's page, [here](https://sites.tufts.edu/znitecki/files/2016/06/amer.math_.monthly.122.9.862.pdf).)